# Distorted line in mesh [Object Mode]

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I have done some sculpting on the mesh (things looked all right) then when I switched to Object mode, I saw some weird lines pointing out from the mesh.

What is causing these (as I see them often) and what are the solutions for these?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Here is my blender file: https://ufile.io/a77d6

Comment: If using the mirror modifier your origin may not be in the center and or clipping need to be checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are duplicate vertices where these lines appear. For Multiresolution this is a problem. Afaik you will have to correct these spots by hand after removing the doubles.
You can see them more clearly in Editmode after pressing Apply Base.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was able to find the duplicated vertices.